# video not showing full screen

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, adobe, video-capture

I have video from multi videos, when I import it in after effect, one of them not showing full screen.
I think when see image will understand my problem

in video player:
[image]

in after effect after imported:
[image]

Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the size of your comp in After Effects is the same as the size of your original video clip. Make sure the clip in your layer is set to scale 100%.

Comment: Also if you want to automatically resize the clip to fit the composition hit ctrl-alt-shift-G or ctrl-alt-shift-H or if you're still on a mac cmd-alt-shift-G/H

Comment: Still not working, the primary video has 2 video which merged, one appears full and the other not :(

Comment: upload some screenshots showing your comp, the comp settings, the video's dimensions etc.